# Problems in reusing a single POJO class for different databases

Tags: oop, orm, solr, rdbms, pojo

I am using POJO (Plain Old Java Object) classes for mapping the relational database and using Apache Solr to index the database.

I don't know whether I can re-use pojo classes for Apache Solr or not.

Since mapping classes are too specific and are designed with foreign key relationship in mind, it is very difficult to use the classes with Solr (a single schema search server), but creating new POJO classes for Apache Solr is also difficult.

So I want to know which is the better design approach for reusing.

Also I would like to know the pitfalls of reusing the same POJO class.

Answer (score 1):

SOLR is very different from a relational database...basically it is something like a big table (with several differences like multivalued columns).

Now, I see your problem a step behind the concrete implementation (POJO)...

First, you have to de-normalize your table(s)...that's the real hard thing you need to do when working with SOLR. I mean passing from your ER to SOLR schema. Once did that, you can use Solrj to map entity with pojo, but this is only the last part of the story.

Still about denormalization: doesn't make sense do a raw translation of a set of POJO mapped on top of a relational database. Relational databases are general-purpose: their design approach is data-centric. I mean, first decide how to store your data and after that SQL clients will be able to get what they need.

SOLR works in a different way: in order to determine moreless exactly your schema you should know your search requirements (i.e. queries). The schema is not general-purpose (like a database) but is tiered on top of search requirements. That's the reason why you could index an atrtribute or not, decide what kind of analysis needs a particular field, multivalued, monovalued, stemming, etc etc etc

So basically, it's all about denormalization and query requirements.